# Remove unnecessary arrays within arrays after map

Tags: javascript

After a mapping an array 3 times i hva gotten this result:

```
[ [ [ [11], [22], [123], [asd] ] ] ]
```

How do i clean this array to become like so:

```
[ [11], [22], [123], [asd] ]
```

cant remember how to do this or word this problem to get a answer. Thanks!!

Comment: [`.flat(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) will probably work for you

Comment: Why have you mapped an array 3 times? Can you achieve the desired result without doing that? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: (I meant `flat(2)`, but ah well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method to flatten your array.

If you know exactly how many levels you need to flatten, you can pass in that as an argument to the method.

In your case you can use `arr.flat(2)`

```js
let arr = [ [ [ [11], [22], [123]] ] ];
console.log(arr.flat(2));
```